# Abort further execution from a nested function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a parent function that contains an ajax call as well as couple of validation functions prior to ajax call. What I am trying to achieve is to obviously run the validation functions first and if any of those fail prevent the further execution of the parent function.

So if I return `null` that would stop the further execution of the function,but how can I return `null` from a child function to affect the parent one?

*Child function (validate)*

```
function trrValidationError(ele, title, text) {
if ($(ele).val() === "") {
    if (title === null) {
         title = "Warning";
    }
    if (typeof text == "undefined") {
        text = "Input validation error!";
    }
    swal({
        title: title,
        text: text,
        type: "error"
    });
    return null;
}
}
```

*Parent function*

```
        EventAdd: function(ele) {
        var form = $(ele).closest("form")[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        trrValidationError($("#webcms-events-description"),null,"Description field must not be empty!"));
        trrValidationError($("#StartDateTime"),null,"Start Date field must not be empty!"));
        trrValidationError($("#EndDateTime"),null,"End Date field must not be empty!"));

        if (trrConfirm("",
            "Are you sure you want to add a new event?",
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formData,
                        url: $(ele).data("url"),
                        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false
                    })
                    .done(function(response) {
                        swal({
                            text: "You have successfully added a new event!",
                            type: "success"
                        });

                        form.reset();
                        var newele = $("<div/>");
                        newele.html(response).contents().insertAfter($("#webcms-events-table-row"));
                    })
                    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                        trrAlert(xhr.responseText);
                    });
            }));
    },
```

Comment: I don't know if I get it right, but why don't you test in your parent function, the value returned by your child one ? like if(trrValidationError(...) != null) {... *keep on* ...} ?

Comment: @r4phG You got it right, I am aware of that solution, i was just looking for a more sophisticated way of doing it, without additional checks in the main function.

Comment: then, I think your child function should return a boolean. So that you can do bool true; bool &= trrValidationError(..) (the number of checks you need to do) and in your if ( bool && trrConfirm(...)).

Comment: Or maybe you can throw an exception in your child function :)

Comment: @r4phG It leads to the same point where i'll have to catch it and do something with it. Anyway, thanks for suggestions.